# Javascript: innerHTML object not filling parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue loading a HTML page as an object into a div using Javascript. The HTML page loads into the correct div but for some reason a scroll bar appears on the side of the div. I'm guessing the issue is something to do with the parent height and width values but I haven't been able to figure it out. I want the text to extend the length of the page. The width is fine but I don't want the scroll bar to be there.

Can anyone help me with this issue? I'd prefer not to use any fixed height or width values as I want my page to be dynamic as possible.

Here are some pictures that hopefully explain the issue.

[image]
When the "Test" button at the top is selected, here's what is displayed.

[image]

Here's the main html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="blog-masthead">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="blog-nav">  
                    <a id="navHome" class="blog-nav-item active">Home</a>
                    <a id="navTest" class="blog-nav-item" onclick="showTest()">Test</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="blog-header">
                    <h1 class="blog-title">This is a test site</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <div id="mainPost" class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
                    <!--Loaded content goes here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function showTest() {
                document.getElementById("mainPost").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="test.html" style="min-width:100%; min-height: 101%;  style="overflow:hidden;" ></object>';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the test.html file that I'm trying to load

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="blog-post">
    <h2 class="blog-post-title">Test</h2>
    <p class="blog-post-meta">October 18, 2015 by Test</p>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what are "col-sm-8 blog-main" classes, do they have overflow defined?

Comment: The "col-sm-8" class is part of Twitter Bootstrap which is referenced in the head. The "blog-main" class is from a separate css file which isn't used in this example. The code I have posted is a simplified version and the "blog-main" class is something I forgot to take out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it works that way with `<object>`, but it works with `<iframe>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="blog-masthead">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="blog-nav">  
                    <a id="navHome" class="blog-nav-item active">Home</a>
                    <a id="navTest" class="blog-nav-item" onclick="showTest()">Test</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="blog-header">
                    <h1 class="blog-title">This is a test site</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <div id="mainPost" class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
                    <!--Loaded content goes here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var url = "data:text/html;base64,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";
          
            function showTest() {
                document.getElementById("mainPost").innerHTML = '<iframe src="'+url+'" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden; border:none;" scrolling="no"  seamless="seamless"></iframe>';
            }
          
            showTest()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I bae64 encoded `test.html` to make this example work. You can replace the variable `url` with `"test.html"`.

Comment: Tim, when I tried your code the div was displayed in a window that was narrower than the object window and it still had a scrollbar on the right hand side

Comment: @Briscoooe Now it does, you can manually change the style so that it fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you've got incorrect style attribute:

```
'<object type="text/html" data="test.html" style="min-width:100%; min-height: 101%;  style="overflow:hidden;" ></object>'
```

Comment: *First of all* suggests you have other things to say.  Also, you don't need the `\`` character when you have 4 leading spaces. Remove them and your code will colour correctly